# Feedback form security

Tags: beginner, php, security, form

I have written a form to collect some feedback, which is written to a CSV file upon an Ajax post. In my feedbackapi.php file I have sanitised, done checks and then written the feedback to a CSV file. I was just wondering if there were any improvements that could have been made for the API.

My form:

```
    <form method="post" id="feedbackform" class="form-horizontal">
    <p class="prog"></p>
<h2>Feedback</h2>
<div id="inf"></div>
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
<h3>Provide feedback on:</h3>
<select class="form-control" id="RatingFor" name="RatingFor"required="required">
      <option name="Programme" value="Programme">My Programme</option>
      <option name="Assessor" value="Assessor">My Assessor</option>
      <option name="Trainer" value="Trainer">My Trainer</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="reqalt">
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
<div>
<label for="progq1">My programme performance in delivering the skills development I need at work is:</label>
<input class='rangeSlider' id='progq1' name='progq1'type="range" min="0" max="4" value="0" required="required"/><span class="range"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
<div>
<label for="progq2">The quality of my programme training facility is:</label>
<input class='rangeSlider' id='progq2' name='progq2'type="range" min="0" max="4" value="0" required="required"/><span class="range"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
<label for="progq3">The level and quality of communication from my programme is:</label>
<input class='rangeSlider' id='progq3' name='progq3'type="range" min="0" max="4" value="0" required="required"/><span class="range"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="reqalt2">
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
<div>
<label for="asq1">My assessors performance in helping me through my programme is:</label>
<input class='rangeSlider' id='asq1' name='asq1'type="range" min="0" max="4" value="0" required="required" disabled="disabled"/><span class="range"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
<div>
<label for="asq2">The frequency of my assessors contact with me is:</label>
<input class='rangeSlider' id='asq2' name='asq2'type="range" min="0" max="4" value="0" required="required" disabled="disabled"/><span class="range"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
<div>
<label for="asq3">My assessors feedback at the end of my assessment visit is:</label>
<input class='rangeSlider' id='asq3' name='asq3'type="range" min="0" max="4" value="0" required="required" disabled="disabled"/><span class="range"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="reqalt3">
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
<div>
<label for="trai1">My trainers technical competence in delivering my training is:</label>
<input class='rangeSlider' id='trai1' name='trai1'type="range" min="0" max="4" value="0" required="required" disabled="disabled"/><span class="range"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
<label for="trai2">My trainers ability to manage the group during my block release is:</label>
<input class='rangeSlider' id='trai2' name='trai2'type="range" min="0" max="4" value="0" required="required" disabled="disabled"/><span class="range"></span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
<label for="trai3">My trainers ability to help me update my portfolio at the end of each training session is:</label>
<input class='rangeSlider' id='trai3' name='trai3'type="range" min="0" max="4" value="0" required="required" disabled="disabled"/><span class="range"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit!</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
</form>
```

My API:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    function createPath($path) {
        if (is_dir($path)) return true;
        $prev_path = substr($path, 0, strrpos($path, '/', -2) + 1 );
        $return = createPath($prev_path);
        return ($return && is_writable($prev_path)) ? mkdir($path) : false;
    }
    function putToFile($dataList){
        $year = date("Y");
        $month = date("m");
        $plugin_folder_name = 'hello-world';
        $plugin_folder_path = "../../../plugins/".$plugin_folder_name.'/';
        $path = $plugin_folder_path.$year.'/'.$month.'/';
        if(createPath($path)){
            $filename = $path."vish.csv";
            if (file_exists($filename)) {
                $file = fopen($filename,"a");
                foreach ($dataList as $line)
                {
                    fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
                }
                fclose($file);
                $sucessmsg = "<div class=\"msg-yes alert alert-success alert-dismissable\"><strong>Success!</strong> Thank you for your Feedback. <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a></div>";
                echo($sucessmsg);

            } else{
                $ourFileHandle = fopen($filename, 'w') or exit("can't open file");
                $headers = ['Apprenticeship_Programme', 'Rating', 'Programme_Performance', 'Quality_Of_Programme','Programme_Communication_Quality','Assessor_Performance','Assessor_Contact_Frequency','Assessor_Feedback','Trainer_Technical_Competence','Trainer_Management_Ability','Trainer_Help_Ability'];
                fputcsv($ourFileHandle, $headers);
                fclose($ourFileHandle);
                putToFile($dataList);
            }
        } else {
            exit('<div class="\msg-no alert alert-warning alert-dismissable\"><strong>Warning!</strong> Something went wrong! Please try again.<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a></div>');
        }
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['last_submit']) && time()-$_SESSION['last_submit'] < 30){exit('<div class="\msg-no alert alert-warning alert-dismissable\"><strong>Warning!</strong> Please wait at least 30 seconds before another submit<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a></div>');}else{$_SESSION['last_submit'] = time();}

    if(empty($_POST['programTitle']) || empty($_POST['RatingFor']))
    {
        exit('<div class="\msg-no alert alert-warning alert-dismissable\"><strong>Warning!</strong>Something went wrong! Please try again.<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a></div>');
    } else{
        $progTitle = isset( $_POST['programTitle'] ) ? filter_var($_POST["programTitle"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING): '';
        if(empty($progTitle)){
            exit('<div class="\msg-no alert alert-warning alert-dismissable\"><strong>Warning!</strong> Something went wrong! Please try again.<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a></div>');
        } else{
            $rating = isset( $_POST['RatingFor'] ) ? filter_var($_POST["RatingFor"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING): '';
            $whitelist = array('Programme', 'Assessor','Trainer');
            if (in_array($rating, $whitelist)) {
                switch($rating){
                case "Programme":
                    $progq1 = isset( $_POST['progq1'] ) && filter_var($_POST['progq1'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options' => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 4))
                    ) ? $_POST["progq1"] : '';

                    switch($progq1){
                    case "1":
                        $progq1 = "poor";
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        $progq1 = "Satisfactory";
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        $progq1 = "Good";
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        $progq1 = "Outstanding";
                        break;
                    default:
                        $progq1 = '';
                    }

                    $progq2 = isset( $_POST['progq2'] ) && filter_var($_POST['progq2'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options' => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 4))
                    ) ? $_POST["progq2"] : '';

                    switch($progq2){
                    case "1":
                        $progq2 = "poor";
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        $progq2 = "Satisfactory";
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        $progq2 = "Good";
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        $progq2 = "Outstanding";
                        break;
                    default:
                        $progq2 = '';
                    }

                    $progq3 = isset( $_POST['progq3'] ) && filter_var($_POST['progq3'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options' => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 4))
                    ) ? $_POST["progq3"] : '';

                    switch($progq3){
                    case "1":
                        $progq3 = "poor";
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        $progq3 = "Satisfactory";
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        $progq3 = "Good";
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        $progq3 = "Outstanding";
                        break;
                    default:
                        $progq3 = '';
                    }


                    if(empty($progq1) || empty($progq3) || empty($progq3)){
                        exit('<div class="\msg-no alert alert-warning alert-dismissable\"><strong>Warning!</strong> Something went wrong! Please try again.<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a></div>');
                    }else{
                        $progData = array("{$progTitle},{$rating},{$progq1},{$progq2},{$progq3},null,null,null,null,null,null");
                        putToFile($progData);
                    }
                    break;
                case "Assessor":
                    $asq1 = isset( $_POST['asq1'] ) && filter_var($_POST['asq1'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options' => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 4))
                    ) ? $_POST["asq1"] : '';

                    switch($asq1){
                    case "1":
                        $asq1 = "poor";
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        $asq1 = "Satisfactory";
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        $asq1 = "Good";
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        $asq1 = "Outstanding";
                        break;
                    default:
                        $asq1 = '';
                    }

                    $asq2 = isset( $_POST['asq2'] ) && filter_var($_POST['asq2'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options' => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 4))
                    ) ? $_POST["asq2"] : '';

                    switch($asq2){
                    case "1":
                        $asq2 = "poor";
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        $asq2 = "Satisfactory";
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        $asq2 = "Good";
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        $asq2 = "Outstanding";
                        break;
                    default:
                        $asq2 = '';
                    }

                    $asq3 = isset( $_POST['asq3'] ) && filter_var($_POST['asq3'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options' => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 4))
                    ) ? $_POST["asq3"] : '';

                    switch($asq3){
                    case "1":
                        $asq3 = "poor";
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        $asq3 = "Satisfactory";
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        $asq3 = "Good";
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        $asq3 = "Outstanding";
                        break;
                    default:
                        $asq3 = '';
                    }

                    if(empty($asq1) || empty($asq2) || empty($asq3)){
                        exit('<div class="\msg-no alert alert-warning alert-dismissable\"><strong>Warning!</strong> Something went wrong! Please try again.<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a></div>');
                    }else{
                        $asqData = array("{$progTitle},{$rating},null,null,null,{$asq1},{$asq2},{$asq3},null,null,null");
                        putToFile($asqData);
                    }
                    break;
                case "Trainer":
                    $trai1 = isset( $_POST['trai1'] ) && filter_var($_POST['trai1'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options' => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 4))
                    ) ? $_POST["trai1"] : '';

                    switch($trai1){
                    case "1":
                        $trai1 = "poor";
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        $trai1 = "Satisfactory";
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        $trai1 = "Good";
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        $trai1 = "Outstanding";
                        break;
                    default:
                        $trai1 = '';
                    }

                    $trai2 = isset( $_POST['trai2'] ) && filter_var($_POST['trai2'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options' => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 4))
                    ) ? $_POST["trai2"] : '';

                    switch($trai2){
                    case "1":
                        $trai2 = "poor";
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        $trai2 = "Satisfactory";
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        $trai2 = "Good";
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        $trai2 = "Outstanding";
                        break;
                    default:
                        $trai2 = '';
                    }

                    $trai3 = isset( $_POST['trai3'] ) && filter_var($_POST['trai3'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options' => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 4))
                    ) ? $_POST["trai3"] : '';

                    switch($trai3){
                    case "1":
                        $trai3 = "poor";
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        $trai3 = "Satisfactory";
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        $trai3 = "Good";
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        $trai3 = "Outstanding";
                        break;
                    default:
                        $trai3 = '';
                    }

                    if(empty($trai1) || empty($trai2) || empty($trai3)){
                        exit('<div class="\msg-no alert alert-warning alert-dismissable\"><strong>Warning!</strong> Something went wrong! Please try again.<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a></div>');
                    }else{
                        $traiData = array("{$progTitle},{$rating},null,null,null,null,null,null,{$trai1},{$trai2},{$trai3}");
                        putToFile($traiData);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            } else{
                exit('<div class="\msg-no alert alert-warning alert-dismissable\"><strong>Warning!</strong> Something went wrong! Please try again.<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a></div>');
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: Sorry @Roland it messed up when pasting here. Would csrf protecton be needed here ?

Comment: @VaishalPatel I'm voting to close as you are not really asking about the code you have, but the code you are going to write. Once you have implemented the functionality, please feel free to post your code for review.

Comment: @VaishalPatel No, you did not mess up your code when pasting it here. It was wrongly indented before.

Comment: @RolandIllig I have edited my post above and included my complete api

Answer (score 1):

- You should format your code properly. That means indentation and consistent whitespace.
- Check your code for typos. If you don't have an IDE with spellchecking, just paste your code into a word processor.
- Validate the generated HTML. You have a typo in there. I won't tell you which one exactly since that's what a validator tool is for.

Aside from that, your current code looks fine. But that is to be expected, since the code really doesn't do much.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to reply. I just ran the form code through a html validator. Didn't pick up any spelling errors

Comment: The broken HTML code is not in the form, it comes from your API code. And the typo is in the API code, not in the generated HTML.